# Excel found unreadable content in <filename>

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have an excel file that contains about 1000 rows.  Each row has an image, kind of like a thumbnail size in one of the columns.  The cell that the image overlaps has a comment which actually contains a bigger version of the same image.

Every now and then when opening the file I get

```
Excel found unreadable content in <filename>.  Do you want to recover
the contents of the file.  If I say No it closes.
```

If I say yes it repairs and removes some parts with the following log:

```
Removed Part: /xl/drawings/vmlDrawing1.vml part.  (Drawing shape)
Removed Part: /xl/drawings/vmlDrawing2.vml part.  (Drawing shape)
```

What then happens is the comments (that contain the bigger version of the image) are all gone on every row.

The file originally contains a macro that runs and once its done I save the file as xlsx which strips the macro out which is fine.

There is no concrete pattern to this behaviour, its not like it happens the first time I re-open it after saving as xlsx or anything.  It can be fine for a while and then suddenly happen.

This is happening on Windows 7, Office 2010

Comment: `The file extension is xlsx and it does contain macros. Im wondering if it should be xlsm?` Yup. Macros will not run in a `xlsx` formatted file. In fact, I don't think they will even be stored in there, at least not Standard Modules.

Comment: Sorry I got that wrong.  The spreadsheet is populated from another spreadsheet that is running the macro.  The spreadsheet with the error does not contain any macros.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it. The issue is due to cache in memory. 
This is the code that resolved the problem for me.

`Public Sub PT_cache_clear()
    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    With ActiveWorkbook
        For Each pc In .PivotCaches
            pc.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
        Next pc
    End With

End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The XML message was given to me was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><logFileName>error076520_01.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\Work\New Work\SOP New Tool.xlsm'</summary><removedRecords summary="Following is a list of removed records:"><removedRecord>Removed Records: Sorting from /xl/worksheets/sheet5.xml part</removedRecord></removedRecords></recoveryLog>
```

I am now able to fixed it after checking my code.

In the sort function in sheet5 of that excel i previously wrote as below:

```
L = Worksheets("Early Response to Check").UsedRange.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Early Response to Check").Sort
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("P1"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AX1"), Order:=xlAscending
    .SetRange Range("A1:AZ" & L)
    .Header = xlNo
    .Apply
End With
```

This is the part it was not able to read and considering it as unreadable content.

I need to change it to  as below:

```
L = Worksheets("Early Response to Check").UsedRange.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Early Response to Check").Sort
    .SortFields.Add Key1:=Range("P1"), Order1:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key2:=Range("AX1"), Order2:=xlAscending
    .SetRange Range("A1:AZ" & L)
    .Header = xlNo
    .Apply
End With
```

And Voila... the error is gone.

Hope this helps someone else as well to rectify such error.

Thanks,
Maitreya